# Render Talisman CSP nonce on Google reCAPTCHA style tag on in Flask-wtf / wtforms form

Tags: recaptcha, flask-wtforms

I successfully setup CSP on my flask app using Talisman, but the only item I haven't managed to get working is adding a nonce to the Google reCAPTCHA `<style>` tag on my Contact form.

I've used the custom flask-wtf `RECAPTCHA_HTML` Config option, and my rendered html now looks like this:

```
<script {{ csp_nonce() }} src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="aYSDvp4uev5dhAGsk6GbGRKEg7UFNmYc1JP9FSKf"></div>
```

How do I get Flask/Talisman/Flask-wtf to render the `{{ csp_nonce() }}` so that my rendered html looks more like this:

```
<script nonce="RYcJMNtXC7nBC4iYECnzildNF6qBMnoT" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="aYSDvp4uev5dhAGsk6GbGRKEg7UFNmYc1JP9FSKf"></div>
```

I've tried escaping the curly braces (ie. using `\{\{`) and adding `|safe` in the html template, but no luck there.

My actual template reads:

`{{ form.recaptcha }}`

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this one is pretty simple if you keep Flask's Contexts in mind. I simple inserted the CSP nonce from Talisman into the `RECAPTCHA_HTML` within the route that loads my Contact form. But, I did have to put `RECAPTCHA_HTML = ''` in my Config.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
'''webapp.links.routes'''

from flask import Blueprint, render_template, current_app
from webapp.routes.links.forms import ContactForm
from webapp import Config, talisman

links = Blueprint('links', __name__)

@links.route("/contact", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact_route():
    '''
    Contact form
    '''

    ## Construct HTML for Google reCAPTCHA with Talisman nonce
    _RECAPTCHA_SRC = '"https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"'
    _RECAPTCHA_CLASS = 'g-recaptcha'
    _RECAPTCHA_SNIPPET = 'data-sitekey="' + Config.RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY + '"'

    _RECAPTCHA_HTML =    '<script nonce="' + talisman._get_nonce() + \
                        '" src=' + _RECAPTCHA_SRC + ' async defer></script>' + \
                        '<div class="' + _RECAPTCHA_CLASS + '" ' + _RECAPTCHA_SNIPPET + '></div>'
    current_app.config.update(RECAPTCHA_HTML = _RECAPTCHA_HTML)


    form = ContactForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():

    ### Normal form validation/handling below here ....
```

This now renders the Google reCAPTCHA with the nonce in the  tag in my HTML like this:

```
<script nonce="RfK9KoHnAipsTmRLFS5KmnaaYIV1we6b" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="aYSDvp4uev5dhAGsk6GbGRKEg7UFNmYc1JP9FSKf"></div>
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future.